# Formbuilder nested validation

Tags: angular, angular10

I have formbuilder inside a formbuilder - nested.

I just want to validate each `firstName`, `middleName` and `lastName` controls of `name` control but I can't seem to get that `name` control of my `salesForm` form group.

I already tried  `get f() { return this.salesForm.name.controls; }` but it didnt work out.

```js
this.salesForm = this.fb.group({
    id: ['', Validators.required],
    name: this.fb.group({
        firstName: ['', Validators.required],
        middleName: ['', Validators.required],
        lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    }),
    email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
    address: ['', Validators.required],
    contactNo: ['', Validators.required],
});

get f() { return this.salesForm.controls; }
```

This is my HTML File.

```
<div class="form-row" formGroupName="name">

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>First Name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && g.firstName.errors }">
        <!-- <div *ngIf="submitted && g.firstName?.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="g.firstName?.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
            </div> -->
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Middle Name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="middleName"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.middleName?.errors }">
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.middleName?.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.middleName.errors?.required">Middle Name is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Last Name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName?.errors }">
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName?.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.lastName?.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
get f() {
    return (this.salesForm.controls.name as FormGroup).controls;
}
```

You have to update your `f()` method like the above.

Also in your html, you have a typo:

`g.firstName?` -> `f.firstName?`

Comment: it has error Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer using this to access the formbuilder inside a formbuilder:

```
get g() { return (this.salesForm.get('name') as FormGroup).controls; }
```